# Find String on Page (Ctrl+F) when jQuery Accordion in Use

Tags: jquery, find, accordion

I am using jQuery accordion plugin to collapse a large page.  It works nicely and is a great way to compact the page but I noticed that when using the Browser search function find (Ctrl+F) it only looks in the open `div` for the search string.

Is there a way to get the browser find to search through all the `div`s (and maybe even open them if found)...  I see why this is not trivial.  The search would have to open the `div`s to show results and this is not obvious...

If there isn't an obvious way to get around this, what would be the approach to doing this programatically?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this option, as described elsewhere:

[Toggle Entire Accordion Functionality with Link or Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778452/toggle-entire-accordion-functionality-with-link-or-button)

I give the user an option to toggle the accordion all together and then they can search with Ctrl+F.

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy solution for an *accordion*, which is designed around the concept that only one "flap" can be open at a time. But you can devise solutions that work if you get rid of that restriction.

For example,

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) { if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey) { ... } });
```

will allow you to trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and pre-emptively expand all your hidden text.

Another approach is not to actually *hide* your text at all, but make it very nearly invisible (very low opacity, or inside a height:1 div, or whatever does not block find but still effectively hides), and then trap the `select` event. Using whatever technique you prefer to find your position in the DOM (e.g. http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html) you can then reactively expand the hidden section in which text was just selected.

If you do get it working, post back here with your results!

Here's a simple but straightforward alternative to accordions with which you can make the ctrl-f event trick work.

In your HTML you can structure it like so:

```
<div class="booklet">
   <h1>Header 1</h1>
   <div>Content in this flap</div>
   <h1>Header 2</h1>
   <div>Content in this flap</div>
   <h1>Header 3</h1>
   <div>Content in this flap</div>
</div>
```

Style the `h1` elements to taste, ensure you give them things like `cursor: pointer` and the appropriate `background-color` to indicate that these are clickable, e.g.:

```
.booklet h1
{
   cursor:pointer;
   background-color:#3cf;
   color:white;
   border-top-left-radius:5px;
   border-top-right-radius:5px;
   padding:5px;
}
.booklet div
{
   display:none;
   border: 1px solid #3cf;
   border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
   border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
   padding:5px;
}
```

In your Javascript:

```
$('.booklet').on("click", "h1", function()
{
   $('.booklet div').hide();
   $(this).next("div").show(); // acts like accordion, animate to taste
});
$('.booklet div').first().show(); // open first flap of accordion to begin

$(document).on("keydown", function (e)
{
   if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey) // ctrl+f
   {
      $('.booklet div').show(); // show all flaps
   }
});
```

All the flaps will remain open until another header is clicked, when it will return to accordion behavior.

Comment: I've never really done anything like this.  Would I take your code snippet and then inside the function, call the opening of the accordion flaps?  Not sure I understand how to use that hint.

Comment: @nicorellius Unfortunately, you can't, because JQuery UI won't let you have more than one "flap" open at a time, rendering your CTRL+F trick useless. I'm saying if you want to do this you'd have to design something similar to but unlike an accordion (from scratch). Then you can apply these techniques.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are saying...  Darn, seems like either way I go a lot of work is required.  Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: @nicorellius At least with autoexpanding headers and the ctrl-f event it's not terribly difficult. I'll demonstrate in an edit.

Comment: Very nice addition.  I rely on the accordion in a few places, so I might look for something simpler to implement.  I'm thinking, perhaps, that I can remove the accordion altogether from a link (thereby expanding the `div`s out all at once on the page) that allows the users to search with Ctrl + F and then they can toggle accordion back if they please.  Otherwise, on page refresh accordion is reinstated.